# $R/I \otimes_A R/I \cong (R \otimes_A R)/(I \otimes_A I)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $f: A \to R$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.

Is it true that $R/I \otimes_A R/I \cong (R \otimes_A R)/(I \otimes_A I)$ ?

After obtaining the surjection $g: R \otimes_A R \to R/I \otimes_A R/I$, I have a problem of showing that the kernel of $g$ equals $I \otimes_A I$; I can only show directly that $I \otimes_A I \subseteq Kerg$.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:** Actually, my question is a special case of an already asked and answered question: [Why does $(A/I)\otimes_R (B/J)\cong(A\otimes_R B)/(I\otimes_R 1+1\otimes_R J)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123543/why-does-a-i-otimes-r-b-j-conga-otimes-r-b-i-otimes-r-11-otimes-r-j)
(this reference appears in a comment of @user26857).

Comment: Try $A=R$. What's going on?

Comment: So this is not true... If I am not wrong, on the left we will have $R/I$, while on the right we will have $R/(I \otimes_R I)$ ?

Comment: On the right we have $R/I^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the kernel of $g$ is $I\otimes_AR+R\otimes_AI$, so the correct isomorphism is $$(R\otimes_AR)/(I\otimes_AR+R\otimes_AI)\simeq R/I\otimes_AR/I.$$

Comment: How can we show that this is the entire kernel without some kind of flatness assumption?

Comment: @Slade This is a notation for the ideal of $R\otimes_AR$ generated by the monomials $a\otimes b$ with $a\in I$ or $b\in I$.

Comment: @Slade If you prefer, $I\otimes_AR$ stands for the image of the map $I\otimes_AR\to R\otimes_AR$.

Comment: @user26857: There is not need to assume that $R$ is flat over $A$?

Comment: @user26857 I understand the notation.  How do we show that this is the whole kernel?  I don't think this is obvious—there may be many ways to write a given tensor.

Comment: @Slade For a proof see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123543/why-does-a-i-otimes-r-b-j-conga-otimes-r-b-i-otimes-r-11-otimes-r-j).

Comment: @user26857: Great! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's be careful: $I\otimes_A I\to R\otimes_A R$ may not be injective, so presumably $(R\otimes_A R) / (I\otimes_A I)$ is supposed to be the quotient by the image of this map.

Anyway, this is false even when $f$ is the identity: then the left-hand side is isomorphic to $R/I$, while the right-hand side is isomorphic to $R/I^2$.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! @user26857: Thanks for the correct isomorphism.

Comment: @user237522 Count me as very skeptical that the other answer gives the correct isomorphism.

Comment: :-) Though I still wish to know why this is exactly the kernel of $g$.