# $k$ be a field , then is it true that $k[x]/(x^m) \otimes _k k[x]/(x^n) $ is isomorphic to $k[x,y]/(x^m , y^n)$ as $k$-algebra s?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, tensor-products, ring-homomorphism

Let $k$ be a field , then is it true that $k[x]/(x^m) \otimes _k k[x]/(x^n) $ is isomorphic to $k[x,y]/(x^m , y^n)$ as $k$-algebra s ?

Unfortunately I am not able to apply any of the properties of tensor products here . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: First step: Look at the generators...

Comment: Maybe the isomorphism here would be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123543/why-does-a-i-otimes-r-b-j-conga-otimes-r-b-i-otimes-r-11-otimes-r-j

Comment: @BenWest : thanks , I see